# Iterate over multiple level childs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, loops, ruby-on-rails-4, associations

I have class comment which has these relation ships

```
  has_many :children, :class_name => 'Tweet', :foreign_key => 'parent_id'
  belongs_to :parent, :class_name => 'Tweet', :foreign_key => 'parent_id'
```

that means that I can have child of a child of a child and so one..

How can I iterate over all of them and make level structure? Classic comment structure where comment is under comment and so one.

thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This gem will help you solve your case.

https://github.com/stefankroes/ancestry

Comment: is it that complicated task that it "need" external gem?

Comment: Gems are there to help us in complex situation so i would rather go for gems to handle such things. Because in your case you donot know how much times you have load your children against comment or child or i would suggest you would add some more option or unlimited scrolling in which after some depth you hit action again and see if more children are there load them until you reach the limit which is similar to pagination.
A part from this, have you tried eagerloading for that comment class. im not sure that will help. but you can try please.
Comment.where(id:  params[:id].includes(:children)

Comment: Yea I think that i'll do it in a way that i'll see just first level and after click i'll see another and another. Do it via ajax. Thank you